# Hosting project in IIS appends project name to the URL and breaks my routing

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a web api 2 project, and in my code I do some routing stuff myself.

I have all my actions going to a single route, so hitting `localhost/<anything>` will always go to one route.

In that route I am doing some custom pattern matching.

If the user goes to `/Kittens/AdoptAKitten/12345`

It will match against a template I have using regex, defined as `/Kittens/AdoptAKitten/{something}`

The problem is when I host my project locally, it ends up at `localhost/KITTENCORP.ADOPTION/` which is the name of my project. As a result the route matching doesn't work.

I am not sure how to take into account this 'root' address. Previously I was just looking at the domain part of the `Uri` object but I need to include this part in the comparison to make it work (or disregard/remove it).

This code will however also be deployed to a server somewhere at which point it will probably be hosted on `adoptionservice.kittens.org` and thus `adoptionservice.kittens.org/Kittens/AdoptAKitten/12345` will be the url. So it has to account for both situations.

Any ideas how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this and wondering the same thing, I fixed it with this code:

```
// When hosted in IIS it may get a virtual path such as localhost/KittenLibrary that needs including in comparisons
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath))
{
    urlStart = UrlCombine(urlStart, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
}
```

UrlCombine is a function I pinched from another SO question:

```
private static string UrlCombine(string url1, string url2)
{
    if (url1.Length == 0)
    {
        return url2;
    }

    if (url2.Length == 0)
    {
        return url1;
    }

    url1 = url1.TrimEnd('/', '\\');
    url2 = url2.TrimStart('/', '\\');

    return string.Format("{0}/{1}", url1, url2);
}
```